# Change a Div element to Span in Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a `dropdown` and a `button` in a `div` wrapped in a `<td>` that displays info to user. Now the user wants to display the `button` to be displayed in line with the `dropdown`. These controls are in a user control and changing this in design `(.ascx)` will affect all pages that use this user control which I don't want. I want to change this based on a criteria which I can form an if condition. My real challenge comes when deciding on approach to do this and how to do this. I have the following ways to do it.

1. Use a `<span>` instead of a `div`(in .ascx) but this affects all pages that his control is used
2. Change the `div` to `span` in `codebehind` for this specific condition(Fair enough)
3. Apply a style for this div to display inline based on this condition.(But this functionality is already provided by  thus I want to leverage span if possible and this approach is my last resort).

Here is some sample HTML for this:

```
        <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DomainValueDropDownList" runat="server" onchange="OnDomainValueChange(this)"
            AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DomainValueDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNewMessage" Text="New value. Please approve." EnableTheming="false" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Input is required."
        ControlToValidate="DomainValueDropDownList" ForeColor="Red">!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <div id="NewDomainValueDiv" runat="server" visible="false">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="newDomainValueTextBox" runat="server" ToolTip="Click the Add button to add this new value"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" CausesValidation="False" ToolTip="Click button to add this new value" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click"
                CausesValidation="False" />
            <asp:Label ID="infoLbl" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="**New Project will be added to selected Platform. Please select the appropriate platform**" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </div>
</tr>
<tr>
    <div id="UpdateDomainValueDiv" runat="server">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
        </td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

I'm referring to the `btnEdit` button and `DomainValueDropDownList` dropdown.

Is it possible to change a `div` element to a `span` element dynamically? Is there another approach I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Have you considered cloning the contents to a span and then when you need to revert it back you clone the information to the div? In between you can remove the empty/duplicate element.

Comment: You mean from code behind? No I didn't know if we can do that and how

Comment: Are you saying that on one specific page that makes use of this user control you need the position of the button to be different?

If so I think that sounds like a job for page specific CSS that overrides the default layout, and not anything code-behind related.

Comment: It's the other way round. This user control is in a page where its common for all users. Just for one specific user thus alignment is different as I mentioned... It's not page based .its user based for same page.